# Version control metadata sometimes missing when I use pm2

Tags: pm2

[image]

What does it depend on?

Repository information in `package.json` ? Nothing different.

Is this a silly question?

UPDATED:
after reading pm2's source code, I found an error occured in `git.parse`.

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/vizion/lib/git.js`

And I try to exec in the repl

`child_process.exec("git show --quiet --format=%H%n%aD%n%s%n% HEAD",function(e,d){console.log(e)})`

it will print 

`{ [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c  git show --quiet --format=%H%n%aD%n%s%n%B HEAD
]
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '/bin/sh -c  git show --quiet --format=%H%n%aD%n%s%n%B HEAD' } 'adce83ece6c0e63112e7c9551ffca798e0130be6\nTue, 12 Apr 2016 16:23:02 +0800\nuser\n%B\n'`

`child_process.exec("git show HEAD",function(e,d){console.log(e)})`

print null

git version too low? 1.7.1
or node version ? 0.12.0

UPDATED: Finaly I found the reason is that git version is too low.
after upgrade git, it works fine.

Comment: Maybe post your update as an accepted answer, so the question is marked as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reading pm2's source code, I found an error occured in `git.parse`.

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/vizion/lib/git.js`

And I try to exec in the repl

`child_process.exec("git show --quiet --format=%H%n%aD%n%s%n% HEAD",function(e,d){console.log(e)})`

it will print 

`{ [Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c  git show --quiet --format=%H%n%aD%n%s%n%B HEAD
]
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '/bin/sh -c  git show --quiet --format=%H%n%aD%n%s%n%B HEAD' } 'adce83ece6c0e63112e7c9551ffca798e0130be6\nTue, 12 Apr 2016 16:23:02 +0800\nuser\n%B\n'`

`child_process.exec("git show HEAD",function(e,d){console.log(e)})`

print null

git version too low? 1.7.1
or node version ? 0.12.0

UPDATED: Finaly I found the reason is that git version is too low.
after upgrade git, it works fine.